# Count number of rows/cells with data based on filters applied

Tags: vba, excel

how to count the number of rows with data based on the filter applied?

All I can find is methods like `xlUp, xlDown` which I cant apply to this as it will give me last row as opposed the number of rows with filtered data.

example

```
1    animal age
2    dog    10
3    cat    15
```

I apply the filter on cat and get the following table:

```
1    animal age
3    cat    15
```

with xlUp or down it will tell me last row number is 3, but obviously there is only 1 row with filtered data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worksheet's [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) can count visible data in a column.

```
dim i as long
i = application.subtotal(103, columns(1))
debug.print i
```

Comment: this is the easiest and straightforward

Answer (score 4):

What about this?, It is counting the visible cells in the first column in a filtered range.

```
Sub test()

data_visible_rows = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

End Sub
```

Comment: This does require the concerned cells to be selected.  If a cell is clicked outside of the desired region then this wouldn't return the desired value, I think.

Comment: Right, the range need to be specified

Comment: you can get around this by using `AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1)…` instead I think.

Comment: Yeah good point, since autofilter behaviors are specified in the functionality.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I'll appreciate if you could edit my answer with your suggestion, i really dont know how to implement it to my answer...

Comment: Edited again because the row number of the header isn't relevant.  It must always be 1 subtracted since a header can't be more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data in Range A1:C3

[image]

and that you applied the filter manually

[image]

then the statement

```
dim rng as Range
set rng = Range("$A$2:$C$3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

would return a reference to a Range with visible cells only. So you leave out the header.

you can then call

```
rng.Count / rng.Columns.Count
```

to obtain the desired result. Of course you could do it in one go without declaring anything. My previous explanation was for instructive purposes only.

```
Range("$A$2:$C$3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / Range("$A$2:$C$3").Columns.Count
```

This should work.

Comment: This will only count the number of rows in the first contiguous visible area of the autofiltered range.

Comment: this does what the op asks

Comment: but only on his sample data and it will soon or later fail on real data and other criteria.  e.g. add another data entry `4 cat 20` and it fails. It always count's only the header row + contiguous visible rows. And the OP asked for "*count the number of rows with data based on the filter applied?*" which means "*count all filtered rows*" and not only "*all contiguous visible rows (starting from header)*"

Comment: you are right .. I will edit

Comment: `Range("$A$2:$C$3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / Range("$A$2:$C$3").Columns.Count` This will also fail if there are invisible columns in between eg. if you hide column B. You need to divide by visible columns only (instead of all columns)

Comment: I don't understand why you would divide anything.  It seems complicated.

Comment: @n8. Well if you divide `total cell count` by `total column count` you get the `total row count` so `visible row count = visible cell count / visible column count` would be a valid solution.

Comment: Aaaaaah I see.  That's certainly the long way around though.

Comment: Kind of a rube goldberg divice.  And prone to failure (#DIV/0) if all the rows are filtered.

Comment: fails even if you delete all data from your worksheet .. go get laid instead